# Is it right to use HAVING clause like this?

Tags: sql

if i group a relation by an attribute a and then i do:

```
GROUP BY a

HAVING count(a) < max(a)
```

Is this the right way to do so?
(I need to get a's that appear in the relation less than the max a do)

Comment: It would help if you could provide sample data, expected output, and you entire current SQL query .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, syntactically, this is correct.  But it does not do what you want.  The `max(a)` is calculating the maximum of the value of `a` -- it has nothing to do with the count.

If you care about the count, I would recommend window functions:

```
select x.*
from (select a, count(*) as cnt, . . .,
             rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from . . .
      group by a
     ) x
where seqnum > 1;
```

This can also be accomplished with a `having` clause:

```
select a, count(*) as cnt, . . .
from . . .
group by a
having count(*) < (select count(*)
                   from . . .
                   group by a
                   order by count(*) desc
                   fetch first 1 row only
                  );
```

Both these queries use ISO/ANSI standard syntax, because your question does not have a database tag.

Comment: Isn't it comparing the number that a appears in i-th iteration to the max appears of a?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not (based on your description of what you need).

Having is a way to use subsetting after the `GROUP BY` was executed.

The count seems unrelated... the criteria you provided will create a bucket for each a value, and will return the buckets where the number of a items in it is smaller then the value.
So in your example, if you have rows which contain the values 1,1,2, and you execute `SELECT a FROM ... GROUP BY a WHERE COUNT(a) < MAX(a)` the result would be 2 (because 1 appears twice, and is equal to 2, not smaller).

You probably want to use sub select for what you described:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE a < (SELECT MAX(a) FROM ...)
```

However, your description is not that specific, so I hope it helps.